# Saving unknown amount of integers without taking too much time/memory

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long divsum(unsigned long long x);

int main()
{
    unsigned long long x;
    cin >> x;
    unsigned long long y[200000];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        cin >> y[i];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        cout << divsum(y[i]) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long divsum(unsigned long long x){
    int sum = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= x/2; i++){
        if(x % i == 0)
            sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I'm doing an online exercise and it says there are possible 2000000 cases in the first line, so I made an array of that amount, however, when I submit the solution it exceeds the time.. so I was wondering what is an alternative and faster way to do this? The program works fine right now, except it exceeds the time limit of the website.

Comment: You should tell what should the algorithm DO, in order to give you better ways to implement it...

Comment: A simple `std::transform` call should work fine. Of course it can't have side effects, either, so it might not depending on how you define `divsum`.

Comment: If your solution exceeds the time, problem usualy lies in the complexity of the algorithm and not in the memory used. However you could use `std::vector<unsigned long long> y(x)` to reduce memory usage.

Comment: You are allocating 1.5Mb array on the stack - it can be long and it can crash.

Comment: Since it is only about time and not memory ..... try `const &` in the divsum i.e, `const unsigned long long divsum & (const unsigned long long & x)`

Also in the for loop .... pre-compute `x/2`. You could use Vectors for memory, but they have over head of push_back and also to copy the entire vector when it has to resize

Comment: Try a trivial `divsum` that always returns `12`, and see if that gets rejected for taking too long. If so, then the problem isn't `divsum`.

Comment: You should probably also note that with 2000000 (two million) cases and an array of 200000 (two hundred thousand) elements, you're well into the land of invoking undefined behavior if `x` exceeds your array size (and you don't need the array regardless, so I'm not really seeing what you hope to gain from it).

Comment: The alogirthm has to find the sum of the divisors of a specific number. At first line, we input a number 0 <= 200000 of how many numbers will follow after it. And we output each sum in a new line after we input all the numbers.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider what tha algorithm is actually doing. For example, there is no need to enumerate to `x/2`. You only need to enumerate to `sqrt(x)`. Each divisor you find has a corresponding counterpart on there *other side* of the square root. I.e. if you know that `2` is a factor, then you also know that `x/2` is a factor. If `3` is a factor, so will be `x/3` etc. Each factor you find will have a counterpart up to , and possibly including `sqrt(x)` (but only if `x` is a perfect square), one factor on either side of the root. I suggest you reconsider that algorithm.

Comment: Memory allocation, regardless of the size, should be a one time event in your program.  Memory allocation is not the cause of the performance drain.  What was the result of your profiling?

Comment: Do you need to store every result or can you output them as you go along?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Store them all and then output.

Comment: I apologize for being insistent on this, but seriously, read my prior comment and check your algorithm. [See it live](http://ideone.com/4Ucd24).

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually, I think this is incorrect, because for example, number 20, sqrt(20) is 4.4721 therefore it only finds the 2 and 4 divisors?

Comment: @user3002211 You're not correct, it finds divisors 2, 20/2, 4, and 20/4. adding them all together, making 21 total. Which is somewhat the point I was trying to make. You only have to check through the quire root, not all the way up to `X/2`. I updated the test data in the posted link to demonstrate your 20 result (which is 21 unless I don't understand your algorithm). If the purpose to add up the *prime factorization tree*, then a recursive solution can be extended. Either way, there is no sense in going beyond `sqrt(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the size of the array, try `vector` and `reserve`.

```
 int main()
    {
        unsigned long long x;
        cin >> x;
         unsigned long long var;
         vector<unsigned long long> y;
         y.reserve(x);
         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x; i++){
          cin >> y[i];
         }for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x; i++){
           cout << divsum(var) << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

And deal in `const &`

```
const unsigned long long & divsum(const unsigned long long & x){
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned long long x2 = x/2
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= x2; i++){
        if(x % i == 0)
            sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What if exercise expects that all input from stdin has to be read before output?

Comment: I know that it's possible to do this way, but the program requires to input all the numbers first, then output the results.

Comment: Ok. Let me edit it to give better answer adhering to the requirement

Comment: Why do we have to use & here? Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm still a beginner with pointers.

Comment: & in the declaration here implies i'm declaring a reference, and not a pointer. Reference points to the same object that is passed, avoiding a copy. So in the code above you are avoiding another copy of a `long long`

Quick overview : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/overview-refs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate the array dynamically, so it will work better in cases where `x < 200000`

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long x;
    cin >> x;
    unsigned long long *y = new unsigned long long[x];
    // you can check if new didn't throw an exception here
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        cin >> y[i];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        cout << divsum(y[i]) << endl;
    }
    delete[] y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does an array in dynamic memory work better than one on the stack or in global memory?  The should all have the same addressing scheme unless dynamic memory is paged to a disk or something.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The program was allocating an array of 200000 elements every time it ran. It means even if x is less then 200000 it is still allocating more memory than it needs and it spends time doing that.

Comment: @Nazar554 that literally means nothing more than changing how big the N is in a `sub esp, N` instruction. It will have *zero* effect on timing. It *can* have a significant effect on a stack overflow, however.

Answer (score 0):

I think your assignment is more complex than you think. Your divsum(x) function should return sum of all divisors of x, right? In this case it's better to factorize the x, and calculate this sum using all the prime numbers (with powers), product of which is equal to the x. Take a look at:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function
```

There are methods for recursive factorization - for example, if you have factorized all numbers until n, you can quickly find factorization for (n + 1). You also need to generate primes, Erathosphene sieve for first 2000000 numbers would be fine.